# GPS tracker with GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services

in the last update of google services, Google has depercated LocationClient api and now say use GoogleApiClient.

Now need create the App with GPS report any 30 seconds to my webserver but dont found (or dont understant) how work this new api.

If you have a example using GoogleApiClient please past the link to see or download.

And if have a Service with GoogleApiClient please past the link

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Google Maps location with low battery usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108326/android-google-maps-location-with-low-battery-usage)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `android sdk` then just checkout following directory  `\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps\src\com\example\mapdemo\`.

It is having one **example** of showing current location in `GoogleMap` and it is **using `GoogleApiClient` to retrieve current location on periodic interval** of 5 seconds as described in following code. You can modify it according to your requirements.

**MyLocationDemoActivity.java**

```
    public class MyLocationDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements
        ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private TextView mMessageView;

    // These settings are the same as the settings for the map. They will in fact give you updates
    // at the maximal rates currently possible.
    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(5000)         // 5 seconds
            .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_location_demo);
        mMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        setUpGoogleApiClientIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpGoogleApiClientIfNeeded() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Button to get current Location. This demonstrates how to get the current Location as required
     * without needing to register a LocationListener.
     */
    public void showMyLocation(View view) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            String msg = "Location = "
                    + LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of {@link LocationListener}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mMessageView.setText("Location = " + location);
    }

    /**
     * Callback called when connected to GCore. Implementation of {@link ConnectionCallbacks}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                REQUEST,
                this);  // LocationListener
    }

    /**
     * Callback called when disconnected from GCore. Implementation of {@link ConnectionCallbacks}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of {@link OnConnectionFailedListener}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out that GoogleMap uses its own location provider, which is not the FusedLocationProvider, so you need to explicitely call `GoogleMap.setLocationSource` to replace it. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108326/android-google-maps-location-with-low-battery-usage

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly your same problem. You need to explicitely use `GoogleMap.setLocationSource()`.

Here is an example: [Android: Google Maps location with low battery usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108326/android-google-maps-location-with-low-battery-usage)